# JavaScript Dom Manipulation to remove text

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-manipulation

I want to remove `?w=150" class="courseimg">` from the below html code.

```html
<td class="ninja_column_0 ninja_clmn_nm_uploadaheadshotofyou footable-first-visible" style="display: table-cell;">
  <img id="courseimg" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1438761681033-6461ffad8d80?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" softmerge-inner"="" style="width: 260px; left: -1px;" class="courseimg">?w=150" class="courseimg"&gt;
  <h2 class="entry-title" id="title">Jane Doe</h2>
  <div class="course-meta">
    <h4 id="fullname">by person Name</h4>
    <h5><small>Category:</small> Art/Interior design<br><small>Language:</small> Czech</h5>
  </div>
</td>
```

There are several HTML nodes on the website so I want to remove them from all of them. I've tried using `querySelector` to select inner HTML and then tried to manipulate it but it's not working. What I'm doing wrong? Maybe type conversion is the issue here?

Js fiddle for this question: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcs02131114/r2mbgkv3/1)

Just remove the extra text along the image `?w=150" class="courseimg">` using javascript.

Comment: Yes. Known issue. Can you put a jsfiddle. Let me try rectify this

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bcs02131114/r2mbgkv3/1/ 

Just remove the extra text along the image `?w=150" class="courseimg">` using javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('courseimg').nextSibling.textContent="";
```

Or, to remove all of them:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.courseimg').forEach(f=>f.nextSibling.textContent="");
```

Also note that in your examples you have mismatched quotes

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is it helps to you, but looks like you have troubles here `<img id="courseimg" src="url" softmerge-inner"=""`  with attribute `softmerge-inner` which has unnecessary double quotes before `=`.